# Internals of javascript addition and subtraction operator?

Tags: javascript, operators

```
alert(5+'5')   \\ 55
alert(5-'5')   \\ 0
```

What is going here?

Comment: +1 for, i was not aware about "alert(5-'5') \\ 0", really weird

Comment: @Amit Yes, javascript is full of shocks. Shared whatever I came across at http://vkanakaraj.wordpress.com/tag/shock/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short terms, nothing wrong here!

The `+` operator is "overloaded" for strings as well and works as a concatenation operator. If you apply `+` to a number and a string it acts like a string concat operator.

The `-` operator is not "overloaded" for strings. If you apply `-` to a number and a string it will try to convert the string to number and then do the subtraction, if possible.